# Как сбросить IP адрес IFCONFIG

Tags: macos, ifconfig

Я изменил свой IP-адрес, используя эту команду:

```
sudo ifconfig set en1 INFORM 192.168. .
```

Но теперь я не могу просмотреть мои IP-адреса маршрутизатора ..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не имею опыта в osx, но предлагаю перезапустить интерфейс:

```
sudo ifconfig en1 down
sudo ifconfig en1 up
```